# Woocommerce - Produtos em destaque

Tags: woocommerce

Boa tarde. Estou precisando de uma ajuda no WordPress, plugin woocommerce, para saber quais campos/tabelas são alterados no banco de dados quando se clica na estrela para colocar um produto em destaque. Até identifiquei os seguintes campos e tabelas:

wp_term_taxonomy:
campo count é incrementado nos registros term_taxonomy_id = 25 e term_taxonomy_id = 31

wp_term_relationships:
são inseridos dois registros (object_id, term_taxonomy_id = 25) e (object_id, term_taxonomy_id = 31)

Mas ainda tem mais que não consigo localizar, porque se eu manipular diretamente no banco dados conforme acima, o produto aparece com a estrela marcada, mas não aparece na tela em produtos em destaque.